# Wi-fi doesn't work without reinstalling after every restart - please help me - 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, restart, reinstalling

Wi-fi doesn't work without reinstalling after every restart - please help me
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and bcmwl driver on Dell Inspiron 15 3521
`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`
the blacklist.conf contains

```
    # This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's be certain that the correct driver wl isn't blacklisted:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. If 'blacklist wl' is listed, remove it. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, let's ask wl to load automatically on boot:

```
sudo -i
echo wl  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if it's working as expected.

Comment: First reaction was: OMG, No!  Someone is answering!  
Second reaction: Oh, It's Chili555 himself! ;) Thanks for helping me out (twice) last week-end with installing 2 different PCs (I however, read the article carefully and didn't need human intervention)